# REST API URI with synchronized

Tags: spring-boot, rest

I'm java developer and I want to make an API document for our company's new project.

For example, assume that there are 2 action logics like below.

```
    synchronized method1() {
      findUserById(String userId);
      createObject();
    }
```

Of course I know that if findUserById and createObject is seperated logic, REST API simply can be:
`GET /api/users/{userId}` and `POST /api/objects`

But in this case, createObject() must be executed only after findUser() succeeds.

How can I write API? It is very ambiguous and makes me confuse.

Or is there any synchronizing keyword or logic in front-end(vue)? If it is, what is the best way(deal with synchronized logic in back-end or front-end)?